# regex negative query on string RE2 google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I do Google sheets and I'm fighting with `REGEXREPLACE` function past few hours, in general I have this:

```
string1: "blah blah blah @abc blah @bcd blah blah"
```

And I want this:

```
string2: "@abc @bcd"
```

I try to extract it with `REGEXEXTRACT(string1,"@[^\s]+")` but this function won't work global, so I use `REGEXREPLACE` to replace everything else than `@abc` and `@bcd` to `""`, but to do that I need to negate `@[^\s]+`!
How to do that?

Comment: Also can try with regexreplace [like this](https://regex101.com/r/iY1gY3/2) `(@\S+\s*)|[^@]+` and replace with `$1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can helps (With $1 substitution):

```
/(?:.*?(@\S*))|(.*)/ig
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/yD5oD7/1)

Comment: How can I accomplish this, but for extracting all instances of text inside brackets with "`t-`", e.g., `[t- text here]` (Note: there are other texts inside brackets, but with different letters, e.g., `[a- text here]` - we don't want these)

Answer (score 1):

*(edit)* I suggested the other answers wouldn't work in Sheets, but I didn't look at @shA.t's answer closely, which in fact works perfectly. This would be the Sheets implementation:

`=REGEXREPLACE(L1,"(?:.*?(@\S*))|(.*)","$1")`

My original answer:

Unfortunately I think the other answers won't work in the context of Google Sheets, which doesn't support "look-aheads" in spreadsheet function regex.

See if this works:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(JOIN(" ",IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(L1," "),"^@.+")))))`

Comment: I think I did test both, and as far as I remember both did work. I stayed with REGEXREPLACE (myStringHere,"(?:.*?(@\S*))|(.*)","$1") because I think it did filter out string exactly, the other solution is very close (I think some white spaces were let in). Anyway both work, thanks lots!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you shA.t ... I was trying to do a similar thing with JSON file extracting data fields using google sheets by including what I wanted then running into the restrictions of RE2 used by sheets. Using REGEXREPLACE and excluding what I didn't want worked like a charm, just substituted by trial and error till It was perfect

```
=REGEXREPLACE(L1,"(?:.*?{("guid":".*?")})|(.*)","$1")
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH3aK7/1)

After looking at it closer I realized I wanted the headers to be removed as well, so the final RE2 is even simpler

```
(?:.*?:(".*?"))|(.*)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC5vZ8/1)